# Increase speed numpy.loadtxt?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have hundred of thousands of data text files to read. As of now, I'm importing the data from text files every time I run the code. Perhaps the easy solution would be to simply reformat the data into a file faster to read. 
Anyway, right now every text files I have look like:

```
User: unknown
Title : OE1_CHANNEL1_20181204_103805_01
Sample data     
Wavelength  OE1_CHANNEL1    
185.000000  27.291955

186.000000  27.000877

187.000000  25.792290

188.000000  25.205620

189.000000  24.711882

.
.
.
```

The code where I read and import the txt files is:

```
# IMPORT DATA
path = 'T2'
if len(sys.argv) == 2:
    path = sys.argv[1]

files = os.listdir(path)
trans_import = []
for index, item in enumerate(files):
    trans_import.append(np.loadtxt(path+'/'+files[1], dtype=float, skiprows=4, usecols=(0,1)))
```

The resulting array looks in the variable explorer as:
{ndarray} = [[185. 27.291955]\n [186.  27.000877]\n ... ]

I'm wondering, how I could speed up this part? It takes a little too long as of now just to import ~4k text files. There are 841 lines inside every text files (spectrum). The output I get with this code is 841 * 2 = 1682. Obviously, it considers the \n as a line...

Comment: `loadtxt` is a simple Python file reader - readline, split, collect list of lists, make array at the end.

Answer (score 3):

It would probably be much faster if you had one large file instead of many small ones. This is generally more efficient. Additionally, you might get a speedup from just saving the `numpy` array directly and loading that `.npy` file in instead of reading in a large text file. I'm not as sure about the last part though. As always when time is a concern, I would try both of these options and then measure the performance improvement.

If for some reason you really can't just have one large text file / `.npy` file, you could also probably get a speedup by using, e.g., `multiprocessing` to have multiple workers reading in the files at the same time. Then you can just concatenate the matrices together at the end.

---

Not your primary question but since it seems to be an issue - you can rewrite the text files to not have those extra newlines, but I don't think `np.loadtxt` can ignore them. If you're open to using `pandas`, though, [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) with `skip_blank_lines=True` should handle that for you. To get a `numpy.ndarray` from a `pandas.DataFrame`, just do `dataframe.values`.

Comment: I agree. Concatenating the files beforehand and then reading that might be faster, or using multiple workers as suggested.

Comment: Thanks, this is definitively the best way to do it! Thing is that every spectrum were acquired at different time. So right now I like to have trans_import[0] being the first spectrum, trans_import[1] the second, etc. How would you save that information in a single file?

Comment: Suppose each of your files has $m$ rows and there are $n$ files with 2 columns each. Do you want the shape of the final array to be $(n * m) x 2$ or $n x m x 2$? From your comment, I'm thinking now that you want $n x m x 2$. To do that, I would read each file like you are doing now (just once; and fixing the `\n` issue) then do `trans_import = np.stack(trans_import)` to put all of the arrays into one big array. Then you can just save it as `np.save("data.npy", trans_import)` or `np.savetxt("data.txt", trans_import)`.

Comment: If this answer solves your problem, please click the check mark on the left side of it to let others know that this question has been resolved.

Comment: If you're going to concatenate the files but still want to keep some meta information, hdf5 will be easier to manipulate than npy files. But definitely, the two key points to speed things up are binary format and avoid too many little files.

Comment: Yes, if you want metadata, look into `pandas` (which you can think of as a wrapper around `numpy` which lets your columns have names and adds some other operations). `pandas.DataFrames` can easily be saved as/read from HDF5 files. (e.g. `df.to_hdf`).

Answer (score 1):

Let use pandas.read_csv (with C speed) instead of numpy.loadtxt. This is a very helpful post:
http://akuederle.com/stop-using-numpy-loadtxt

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: the link is now 404